# How to create a See-Through View in Android XML-Layout

Tags: android, xml, transparent

My Android XML-Layout looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:background="?android:colorBackground"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <SomeView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

What I need is a 'See-Through' hole in my Background LinearLayout at the size of my small View. Like in the following Picture:

[image]

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Please consider marking an answer and/or upvoting good answers.

Comment: @Marcel did you find any solution for this?

Comment: no, i dont think so

Answer (score 1):

use transparent background in views that you want to make transparent so if there is any view behind it it will display

eg:

```
 android:background="#00000000"
```

- Normal opaque black hex- "#000000"
- Fully transparent - "#00000000"
- Fully opaque - "#FF000000"
- 50% transparent - "#80000000"

Comment: but it must went through the unterlying layout and show whats behind this. take a look at the picture.

Comment: parent one with red  a child in it lets say a relative one(a white one) which goes in the middle and in that another layout which is transparent so it fulfill your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you wish a see-through background for the view, what can be done is :-

- Layout 1 : Take a parent layout filling the background as -  android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="match_parent" : Say red color
- Layout 2 : Now take another layout filling whatever size of the screen is needed : Say blue color
- View : You can place your view [the see through one] in this layout and layout_width=20px, layout_height = 20px and background color should be the same as that of Layout1 that is red. This would now look like a see-through hole in the blue background.

Hope that this helps.

Example :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="30dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Im pretty sure you will see the blue background through this. Any example?

Comment: I have added code snippet which will show you a red see-through view on a blue background.

Comment: but what if bottom LL has background image and i want to see a part of this in the top View?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the Alpha channel - I think that's basically what you're looking for here.